# Best practice to call database async methods without blocking ui UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, async-await

I have an app that gets some data from a SQLite database. For example, I have a method like the following one:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskItem>> GetAllAsync()
{
    using (var context = new NotesContext())
    {
        try
        {
            return await context
                .Tasks
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<TaskItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

I call this method from a command that is binded when the page loads:

```
LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand<TaskItemViewModel>
            ((task) => GetAllTasksAsync(task));
```

And the method that the command calls:

```
public async void GetAllTasksAsync(TaskListItemViewModel taskList)
{
    ShowTaskListViewProgressRing = true;

    Tasks.Clear();
    TaskAutoSuggestBoxItems.Clear();

    var response = await _dataService
        .TaskService
        .GetAllAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    var tasks = _mapper.Map<List<TaskItemViewModel>>(response);
    if (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var mainTasks = tasks
            .Where(t => t.ParentTask == null);
        mainTasks.ForEach(t =>
        {
            if (!tasks.Any(st => st.ParentTask == t.TaskID))
                return;
            t.SubTasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskItemViewModel>(
                tasks
                .Where(st => st.ParentTask == t.TaskID)
                .OrderBy(st => st.Position));
        });
        Tasks.AddRange(mainTasks);
        TaskAutoSuggestBoxItems
            .AddRange(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ItemModel>>(mainTasks.OrderBy(t => t.Title)));
    }
    CurrentTaskList = taskList;
    ShowTaskListViewProgressRing = false;
}
```

If I'm not wrong, `GetAllTasksAsync` gets called by the UI thread, but when it reaches `GetAllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)` it steps out of its context, then `GetAllAsync` runs in the thread pool context and when it completes it goes back to the UI thread and updates the view properties.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Is `TaskAutoSuggestBoxItems` a UI control?

Comment: @JohanP its an `ObservableCollection`property that is binded to the `ItemsSource` of an AutoSuggestBox

Comment: If you don't touch any UI controls inside `GetAllTasksAsync` then using `configureAwait(false);` is fine, otherwise you'll get an exception due to the context not getting captured and the continuation will run on a threadpool thread.

Comment: @JohanP  by ui controls in this context could it be binded properties? if thats correct `Tasks` and `TaskAutoSuggestBoxItems` are binded to the view, so the app should crash right?

Comment: Source properties are not the same thing as UI *target* properties. You can't touch a control from a background thread but you can set a source property of a view model.

Comment: @mm8 ahh i get it, ui target properties are those like TextBlock.Text. So if i do the following  `string text = await SomeMethod().ConfigureAwait(false)` `myTextBlock.text = text` the app will crash because the current thread is not th ui one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this approach correct?

Catching en exception and pretend like nothing happened like this is not best practice:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<TaskItem>();
}
```

If `GetAllAsync()` can't handle exceptions in a meaningful way, you might as well avoid catching any exceptions and let the caller take care of this. Or you may want to log an error and then re-throw the exception:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskItem>> GetAllAsync()
{
    using (var context = new NotesContext())
    {
        try
        {
            return await context
                .Tasks
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log ex...
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Also an async method that doesn't return a value such as `GetAllTasksAsync` should return a `Task` and not `void`:

```
public async Task GetAllTasksAsync(TaskListItemViewModel taskList){ ... }
```

Otherwise you can't await it when you call which you should.

Your assumptions about the capture of the `SynchronizationContext` and `ConfigureAwait` are correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you anwser, yes i know that the current try catch is not  the best.., letting that aside, so if `GetAllTasksAsync` should return a Task then my command would look like `LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand<TaskItemViewModel>
            (async (task) => await GetAllTasksAsync(task));` in this case why should i await for GetAllTasksAsync?. According to a comment by @JohanP since im touching properties that modifies the ui after the `GetAllAsync()ConfigureAwait(false)`, the app should crash but in my case it doesnt

Comment: Why would setting a source property of a view model crash the application?

Comment: And a RelayCommand isn't async. But any async method should still return a Task.

Comment: Ok, when i call  `var response = await _dataService.TaskService.GetAllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); ` The content of  `GetAllAsync() ` is still called by the ui thread right? so should i add a `ConfigureAwait(false)` to the `return await context
                .Tasks
                .ToListAsync();` or should i wrap the content of the method within a  `Task.Run() ` ?

Comment: `GetAllAsync()` is executed synchronously on the calling thread until it hits an await. `async`/`await` doesn't cause any new threads to be created.  Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask several different questions in the comments field.